# Laravel insert data from one table to another table error

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to get the `product_id` from table one then inserting it to table two, but gives back an error

> 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `product_details` (`product_id`, `category`, `brand`, `provider_id`) values (, Peripherals, Riders, 1))

**Code:**

```
$product = Product::create([
     'product_name' => $request['product_name'],
     'quantity' => $request['quantity']
]); 

$product->save();
$product_id = $product->id;

$productDetails = ProductDetails::create([
    'product_id' => $product_id,
    'category' => $request['category'],
    'brand' => $request['brand'],
    'provider_id' => $request['provider_id']
]);
```

Fillable for **productdetails** model

```
protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'category', 'brand', 'provider_id'];
```

Database structure: (Just remembered, just a while ago I made some changes on my database that was the time when this error popped out.)

**Products:**

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('product_id');
            $table->string('product_name');
            $table->integer('quantity');
```

**Product Details:**

```
Schema::create('product_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('category',255);
            $table->string('brand',255);
            $table->integer('provider_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('product_id')
            ->references('product_id')
            ->on('products')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

---

**This has been solved**,

It was just a simple mistake on my part. I should've been using `'product_id'` at `'$product_id = $product->id'` instead of `'id'`. Apologies to everyone.

Comment: what is the output of this `dd($product_id);`?

Comment: And show the **fillable** properties of ProductDetails model

Comment: @InzamamIdrees outputs the id of the product.

Comment: Is your id being generated?

Comment: product_id is auto incremented, so yes

Comment: @Nel The problem is in your fillable property check my answer

Comment: @InzamamIdrees uhmm i made an error sorry about that. i just edited the fillable again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before inserting into `ProductDetails` check if `Product` is saved or not. Also check your fillable field in your `ProductDetails` model whether you have added `product_id` or not.

```
    $product = Product::create([
            'product_name' => $request['product_name'],
            'quantity' => $request['quantity']
        ]); 

    if($product) {
        $productDetails = ProductDetails::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'category' => $request['category'],
            'brand' => $request['brand'],
            'provider_id' => $request['provider_id']
        ]);
    }
```

Update your **fillable** field like below:

```
protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'category', 'brand', 'provider_id'];
```

**Update**

If your primary key is `product_id`, you should call `$product->product_id`

Comment: I did just checked, it does insert a product in the table but then returns an error for ProductDetails

Comment: Did you check your  fillable field in `ProductDetails` model?

Comment: yes the fillable is the same as the one you just suggested. But still gives back the same error

Comment: Are you sure `Product` model has `id`?

Comment: Maybe you changed the primary key.

Comment: on my Product model I set the primaryKey to product_id

Comment: So you should call $product->product_id

Comment: Jesus Christ, just that single mistake and i made you guys waste all your time. Thank you Manzurul and apologies.

Comment: I agree. That was a giant waste of time.

Comment: Updated my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have to change your **fillable** property like this:

```
protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'category', 'brand', 'provider_id'];
```

Comment: yes i pasted the wrong fillable awhile ago sorry. still same problem

Comment: You have to change your fillable to this flow..... check the order like this..... 
`'product_id', 'category', 'brand', 'provider_id'`

Comment: Changed the flow and still gives back the same error.

Comment: show the database structure of product and productdetails

Comment: just edited to show the migration of the database for both.

Comment: If I'm not telling you show the db structure, no one solve your question because it's a minor mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use `save()` method. after `create()` method you can get model object and get the id from it directly but make sure your id in db is `id` not `product_id`.

```
$product = Product::create([
            'product_name' => $request['product_name'],
            'quantity' => $request['quantity']
        ]); 

 if($product){
    $productDetails = ProductDetails::create([
        'product_id' => $product->id,
        'category' => $request['category'],
        'brand' => $request['brand'],
        'provider_id' => $request['provider_id']
    ]);
 }else{
    echo "Something went wrong";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify either a `fillable` or `guarded` attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

Fillable you specify which fields are mass-assignable in your model, So in the model you need to add also *`product_id`*:

**Model:**

```
protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'category', 'brand', 'provider_id'];
////only the field names inside the array can be mass-assign
```

---

Automatically assumes your primary key column is going to be `id`. In order for this to work correctly, you should set your primary key in your model `product.php`:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
```

Comment: yes i pasted the wrong fillable awhile ago sorry. still same problem

Comment: yes changed it in the model primarKey is set to 'product_id' for table product

Comment: @Nel you should set your primary key in your model `protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';`

Comment: Yes my primary key for the product table is already set to 'product_id'

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run a **save()** method after running a **create**; its redundant.

You can run a db transaction in a try and catch to know what exactly is going wrong.

```
try {
    \DB::transaction(function () use($request) {
        $product = Product::create([
            'product_name' => $request['product_name'],
            'quantity' => $request['quantity']
        ]);

        $productDetails = ProductDetails::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'category' => $request['category'],
            'brand' => $request['brand'],
            'provider_id' => $request['provider_id']
        ]);
    });

    dd('successful');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    dd( $e->getMessage() );
}
```